# leaflet.js refresh map onclick

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet

I am using [Leaflet](http://leaflet.com) to visualize map. Everything worked fine, until I added a checkbox to switch the data for the map. 
I wrote it like this for the view:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="switch" class="switch-checkbox"onclick="change();" checked>
```

For the function in js :

```
function change()
{
    var map = L.map('map').setView([37.8, -96], 4);

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18
    }).addTo(map);

    if (document.querySelector('.onoffswitch-checkbox').checked) {
        data = statesData;
        L.geoJson(statesData).addTo(map);
    } else {
        L.geoJson(statesDataTwo).addTo(map);
    }
```

Then I got an error that the map is already initialized. I tried to add `map.remove();` before adding the new map. Like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186428/refresh-leaflet-map-map-container-is-alreay-initialized). But map is undefined. What is the way to do that? Thanks

Comment: Can you try to convert your issue into a `jsFiddle`? If you do that, it would be easier to help and while doing so there are chances that you might find the fix yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you adding new map? You probably have it already in global variable `map`, which is initialized on load. Work with this and change only layers on change/click. Something like this:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([37.8, -96], 4);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);

var geojsonLayers = {
    'states': L.geoJson(statesData),
    'statesTwo': L.geoJson(statesDataTwo)
};

function change()
{
    if (document.querySelector('.onoffswitch-checkbox').checked) {
        map.addLayer(geojsonLayers.states);
        if (map.hasLayer(geojsonLayers.statesTwo)) {
            map.removeLayer(geojsonLayers.statesTwo);
        }
    } else {
        map.addLayer(geojsonLayers.statesTwo);
        if (map.hasLayer(geojsonLayers.states)) {
            map.removeLayer(geojsonLayers.states);
        }
    }
}
```