# Leaflet - refreshing the map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I understand that this question has been asked, and answered before, but I haven't been able to successfully implement those examples.

I'm trying to load the map via `zoomedIn()` (works fine), then on the button press load the map with `zoomedOut()`

In `zoomedOut()` however, I'm throwing `Map container is already initialized` after `var map = new L.Map('map');`

I had thought that the previous line `if (map != undefined) { map.remove(); }` would have taken care of that.

What's going on - how can I redraw the map?

```
<body onLoad="javascript:zoomedIn();">
<form method = "post">
<button type="button" onclick="return zoomedOut()">Zoom Out</button>
<div id="map"</div>
</form>

<script language="javascript">
  function zoomedIn() {
     var map = new L.Map('map');
    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
    }).addTo(map);
         var devon = new L.LatLng(50.900958,-3.370846);
         map.setView(devon, 7);
      }
</script>

<script language="javascript">
  function zoomedOut() {
    if (map != undefined) { map.remove(); }
    var map = new L.Map('map');
    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
    }).addTo(map);
         var devon = new L.LatLng(50.900958,-3.370846);
         map.setView(devon, 1);
      }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Why would you want the map to be removed and then added again ?

Comment: I've got a bunch of markers on the map - I'm trying to redraw those markers. That's not in the code above of course, but as I understand it I need to redraw it.

Comment: As here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186428/refresh-leaflet-map-map-container-is-alreay-initialized

Comment: If you are trying to redraw some markers, your question should be titled "How to redraw Leaflet markers?"

Comment: What I'm trying to do is understand why I'm getting the behaviour I'm getting. I deliberately didn't include my end goal in the question.

Comment: First : i verified that the result of the "remove" method call leaves the map object as undefined : it's not. Second : to redraw markers, it's useless to destroy the entire map. You could keep track of the currently displayed markers (in an array for example), remove them and add them again. You could also move them with "setLatLng()" method. Anyway, i can't think about any reason to destroy and create a new map to refresh information on the map...

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
map.invalidateSize()
```

It worked for me