# Leaflet Map container is already initialized

Tags: javascript, html, function, leaflet

I use classic JS to display a LeaFlet MAP into a ```

```
function getMap(latitude,longitude){
    var osmUrl='https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    var osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {minZoom:2, maxZoom:19}); 
    var googleStreets = new L.tileLayer('https://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{minZoom:1, maxZoom:19, subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']});
    var googleSat = new L.tileLayer('https://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{minZoom:1, maxZoom: 21,subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']});
    var map = new L.Map('mapDiv', { doubleClickZoom:false, zoomControl:false, maxBounds:([[90,-270],[-90,270]]) });
    L.control.layers({"OSM (Mapnik)": osm, "Google Street": googleStreets, "Google Earth": googleSat}).addTo(map);
    map.addLayer(osm);
    var map_set = "osm";
    map.setView(new L.LatLng(latitude,longitude),zoom);
}
```

on a button I call `getMap(latitude,longitude)` and it works fine
But if I call again (with new coordinates) than I get the Error **Map container is already initialized.**

Now I understand I need a new function with `map.setView(new L.LatLng(latitude,longitude),zoom);` but then I get map not defined. I need a prod to define the map "global" and final initializing by function and a separate function to display a point on map. Thank's for help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [refresh leaflet map: map container is already initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186428/refresh-leaflet-map-map-container-is-already-initialized)