# How to select different leaflet js files when a button is clicked on the client side

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twig, leaflet

I have several js files in my host/public/js folder. In my html I have a list with several links, representing the js files.

What I am trying to achieve is, when a link is clicked (e.g. `<a href="">file1.js</a>`) the file1.js (referenced in `<head> <script src="/js/file1.js" type="text/javascript"></script> </head>` in my html file) should be used for displaying maps created using leaflet (a JavaScript library for interactive maps).

Is there a way to create this "javascript file selection" tool using PHP, Javascript, twig, or jquery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically load a JavaScript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294/dynamically-load-a-javascript-file)

Comment: May the scripts be pre-loaded or not?

Comment: What do you exactly mean with "pre-loaded"??? sorry, i am new in the business :-/

Comment: Though it is possible to dynamically load js files, loading new js files is not suitable for the task at hands (mostly because you can't get rid of a script once it's loaded). Search for "SPA" to find a better technique for the task.

Comment: @nico, without knowing anything about your goals, it's hard to advise you on a best course of action. By 'pre-loading', I mean to simply include (<script>) the scripts in the page header (<head>). If you just need to call different functions that reside in different files, this may do the job, but may also be suboptimal. A cleaner but more complex way may be to retrieve (download) the files when you need them. Please specify your goals for a more specific answer.

Comment: @RoAchterberg "_should be used for displaying/formatting my content_" says enough, dynamically loading js files for this is not a good idea.

Comment: It would be tricky to dynamically add Js to format content, it would mean that each file should be compatible with any other Js previously loaded (can undo what's been formatted before). An easy solution would be to reload the whole page with a parameter (for example a GET through the URL) and that PHP inserts the right script tag to the page.

Comment: my js files are web-maps (leaflet). The idea is to display a different map (js file) when a link is clicked

Comment: Yes, that is possible. What have you tried so far, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was tackling my problem the wrong way. The solution was https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/.

I get my js scripts asynchronously from the server. The containers (where the maps are rendered) are reloaded using `document.getElementById('id_map_container').innerHTML = "<div id='map'></div>";` (see [refresh leaflet map: map container is already initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186428/refresh-leaflet-map-map-container-is-already-initialized))

In the example above there is just one leaflet and the data (yellow points) are fetched and displayed on the basis map.

In my case, I have lots of js files that have to be requested. So the solution was `jQuery.getScript( url [, success ] )`, which is actually the short hand  and equivalent of

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "script",
  success: success
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible you tackle with your problem the wrong way.

Basically, what you want to do is to change the state of your page when something is clicked on this page. And to do so, you need to fetch something from your server.

I think you should consider this:

You have only one javascript file you could call application.js that you load with the script element. In this file, you will have all your javascript code.

When the click happens, your code will execute an asynchroneous request to fetch data from your server and change your page accordingly.

Example (with jQuery):

```
    $.ajax({
            url: url,
            jsonp: false,
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function(data){
            processJSON(data);
        });
```

Full example here: http://franceimage.github.io/map/

When you click on the 1rst icon for the left sidebar, you can select a different set of points. It then fetches the data from the server ([/map/data](https://github.com/franceimage/franceimage.github.io/tree/master/map/data)) and changes the look of the map.

Is it what you need ?